# Can I pass html string arrays to wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

**Possible to use php functions in wkhtmltopdf class?**

I am using wkhtmltopdf class for generating pdf. I am able to generate the whole HTML into pdf file but i want to do customizations according to requirement. Right now i am using the below code:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;`
$pdf = new Pdf;
$pdf->addPage('http://localhost/ckm/campaign/create-campaign');
$pdf->send();
```

But instead of this i want to use below code that is now giving any output.

```
$pdf = new Pdf;
$pdf->addPage('Voucher'.' : '.$data['voucher_code']);
$pdf->addPage(content_formatter($description->post_content));
$pdf->send();
```

Please suggest me the solution ... 
Thank you.